# mean independence vs statistical independence vs zero correlation

Tags: correlation, independence

Could somebody please explain the difference between the terms:

"mean independence", "statistical independence" and "zero correlation"

As far as I understand, having done my own study (I am not a student), mean independence between two random variables (r.vs) $X$ & $Y$ refers to $E(Y|X)=Y$, indicating that the knowledge of values of $X$(or the variation therein) does not tell us anything about the values of (or variation in) $Y$.

Zero correlation or zero covariance is relatively straightforward in that both connote that there is no linear relationship between the two r.vs.

And I think statisical independence refers to "no functional relationship whatsoever" between $X$ & $Y$.

While I am learning econometrics on my own, I am not really sure about these concepts. Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by a "functional" relationship?

Comment: that $Y$ is not a function of $X$, i think

Comment: What about if the scatterplot of $X$ and $Y$ forms an X-shape or a circle? // I also think you meant to type that $\mathbb{E}[Y\vert X] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Comment: I guess if the scatterplot of  and  forms an X-shape or a circle then there is no functional relationship, and there is none if $\mathbb{E}[Y\vert X] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$, since knowledge $X$ tells us nothing about $Y$. So I revise my understanding of conditional mean.